# Hidden state and hidden sequence in HMM

Tags: conditional-probability, hidden-markov-model, state-space-models

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_algorithm) mentions that "A belief state can be calculated at each time step, but doing this does not, in a strict sense, produce the most likely state sequence, but rather the most likely state at each time step, given the previous history".

I got confused while reading above line, if at every consecutive time step, we compute most like state (belief state) using Forward algorithm then at the end of time the computed belief states should represent the complete state sequence. Why is this contradictory to above statement?

Comment: Are you familiar with the idea of [greedy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) optimization?

Comment: You might be confused about two things. First, it matters very much what your probabilities are conditioned on. Are you conditioning on all possible information, or are you conditioning on all information up to the point in time of the state you're looking at. Second, a probability distribution only factors if the random variables are (conditionally in this case) independent. If you have a distribution for, say, the third state in time, and separately the fourth state in time, you have the marginal distributions. The mode of these will be the most likeley values. But the mode of the joint

Comment: distribution of the third and fourth states together is different. You may get different states because certain values for the third cohere better with different values of the fourth.